# how to give the country,state list is dynamically in input text field using j query for editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My question is how to get drop down list without using select tag in input text field. I am getting the dynamical country and state list in json but i am struggling how to display the list in jsp form ,please help.

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("<c:url value='/user/getUserProfileDetails'/>", {
      ajax: 'true'
    }, function(data) {
      var profileDetails = data;
      $("#ucountry").val(data.getProfileDetails[0].country);
      $("#ustate").val(data.getProfileDetails[0].state);

    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="country"><span class="req"> </span> Country: </label>
  <input required type="text" name="ucountry" id="ucountry" class="form-control ucountry" placeholder="country" />

</div>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="state"><span class="req"> </span> State: </label>

  <input required type="text" name="ustate" id="ustate" class="form-control ustate" placeholder="state" />
</div>
```

[image: Sample]

As the picture shown, my output is coming but i want to put it in input text field drop down list. I am not familiar how to write this code.

Comment: but if you want to show a country list  how you can show in Text file

Comment: that is only i am asking , i also don't know how to display the list in text field if is it possible to display the list in text field

Comment: post your json           here so i can check

Comment: {username: "abcd", email_id: "abcd263@gmail.com", mobile_number: "123456789",…}
city
:
"Krishna"
country
:
"India"
email_id
:
"abcd263@gmail.com"
mobile_number
:
"123456789"
state
:
"Andhra Pradesh"
username
:
"vijayalakshmi"  like my json data is comming

Comment: so you just want to display or give user to choose any country or city name or just type it there

Comment: yes,but whatever user is given in register time values for country,state that values i want to show in edit form initially

Comment: It can be made with css. Wrap your input field in a doc with "position: relative", then add another div inside here after the input which will be your drop-down. Style it as you please, but set "position: absolute". You might have to add "z-index: 1". If you wish to have an example made I can do this later